# How to solve $(1-x^2) y' (x) - 2x y(x) = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying a first-order ODE with non-constant coefficient:

> $$(1-x^2) y' (x) - 2x y(x) = 1$$

IMHO, *Variation of Parameters* is used for second-order ODE with non-constant coefficient. I'm unable to separate $x$ from this ODE.

Could you please help me solve this ODE? Thank you so much!

Comment: Integrate directly...thats easy And the differential is also exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1-x^2)y'-2xy=1 \implies y'-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}y=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
The integrating factor for this  linear ODE is
$$I=\exp[\int \frac{-2x}{1-x^2} dx]= \exp[\ln(1-x^2)]=(1-x^2).$$
So its solution is
$$y=(1-x^2)^{-1} \int dx+C(1-x^2)^{-1} \implies y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{C}{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate directly:
$$(1-x^2) y' (x) - 2x y(x) = 1$$
$$((1-x^2)  y(x))'= 1$$
Integrate:
$$(1-x^2)  y(x)= x+K$$